# PHPexcel duplicating cell data within cell

Tags: php, drupal-7, phpexcel

I have an xlsx file I'm loading and saving with phpexcel, and when I simply load and save the file, I get a duplication of data with cells.

I have an address field cell that looks like this:

```
name
address
state
```

and when I load and save the file with the code below it becomes

```
name
address
statename
address
state
```

I'm loading an .xlsx file created by phpexcel and saving with the following code.

```
$spreadsheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($path);
```

I've tried explicitly setting these cells to be FORMAT_TEXT:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E2:E'. $lastFullRow)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

But no dice. I'm at something of a loss. I confirm that commenting out the load and save above fixes the duplication issue. I tried changing the format of the cell before I save it to rich text and back to normal. Still duplicating.

If it makes any difference the file was generated using Drupal phpexcel: https://www.drupal.org/project/phpexcel

Comment: There is nothing in PHPExcel itself that will automatically add content in a cell, can you post an example of this spreadsheet on the [PHPExcel codeplex site issues log](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced) so that it's possible to investigate further where this strange behaviour comes from

Comment: Thanks! Follow up bug filed here, with the spreadsheet that can be used to replicate the bug: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/21223